# Default JSF Form Behavior

Tags: forms, jsf

I'm building a vanilla JSF app, and I'm having some difficulty understanding how forms work in this framework.

If I make a JavaScript form submission ...

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

... on this JSF form ...

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  ...
  <h:commandButton value="Continue" action="#{foo.continueButton}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

... how can I define the method to be called in the foo bean? Is there a JSF standard way to define a default form submission method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a JSF standard way to define a default form submission method?

Unfortunately no, not in JavaScript.

You could simulate a click on the button to perform an action though.

Comment: Is it just me, or was this a huge oversight?